# Not able to click on a link. I'm getting the error 'Element is not clickable at point'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can't click link.
I see error

> ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element  is not clickable at
>   point (116,32) because another element  obscures it

My code:

```
URL = "https://lenta.com/goods-actions/weekly-products/"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(2)

# ans = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Казань") this link works OK
ans = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Санкт-Петербург") # ERROR
ans.click()
time.sleep(5)
print("go next")
driver.get(URL)
```

**Important** code doesn't work only for **"Санкт-Петербург"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 text strings with a value of "Санкт-Петербур" on this page.  One is in the overlay; one is in the page header.  The script is trying to click the link in the header (but can't because the overlay has focus).

```
from selenium import webdriver

URL = "https://lenta.com/goods-actions/weekly-products/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
ans = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Санкт-Петербург") 
print(ans.get_attribute("class"))
#=> link current-store__link js-pick-city-toggle
```